# WP_Query passing the term in the query

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wp_query to build a list of posts from my CPT, however I need to filter this list by it's term, I can run a tax query which again is fine.

However I also need the term to be in the array of the query for each post.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

i think you can you can use below code to show terms inside loop.

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms( $postId, 'my_taxonomy', array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );
```

Comment: You're right this will get the terms however I need what it returns in the query that gets my custom posts not an additional array.

P.s. Thank you for your help : )